# Akka quartz scheduler does not trigger the jobs

Tags: java, akka, quartz-scheduler

I try to use this [akka-quartz-scheduler](https://github.com/enragedginger/akka-quartz-scheduler) in my play project.
I created two akka actors, added configuration for actors:

```
akka {
  quartz {
    schedules {
      HELLO_ACTOR {
        description = "A cron job that fires off every 10 seconds"
        expression = "0/10 0 0 ? * * *"
      }
      CLEANUP_ACTOR {
        description = "A cron job that fires off every 10 seconds"
        expression = "0/10 0 0 ? * * *"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I created module and add scheduler where i bind actors and scheduler:

```
protected void configure() {
        bindActor(HelloActor.class, HelloActor.NAME);
        bindActor(CleanupRunner.class, CleanupRunner.NAME);
        bind(QuartzSchedulerHelper.class).asEagerSingleton();
        bind(QuartzSchedulerExtension.class).toProvider(SchedulerJobInitializer.class);
    }


    private static class SchedulerJobInitializer implements Provider<QuartzSchedulerExtension> {
        private final QuartzSchedulerExtension quartzSchedulerExtension;

        @Inject
        public SchedulerJobInitializer(ActorSystem actorSystem) {
            this.quartzSchedulerExtension = new QuartzSchedulerExtension((ExtendedActorSystem) actorSystem);
        }

        @Override
        public QuartzSchedulerExtension get() {
            return quartzSchedulerExtension;
        }
    }
```

When application starts, I see in the log that actors were added to scheduler:

```
2018-07-06 11:51:44,947 [INFO] from org.quartz.impl.DirectSchedulerFactory in play-dev-mode-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2 - Quartz scheduler 'QuartzScheduler~application

2018-07-06 11:51:44,947 [INFO] from org.quartz.impl.DirectSchedulerFactory in play-dev-mode-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2 - Quartz scheduler version: 2.2.3

2018-07-06 11:51:44,950 [INFO] from org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler in play-dev-mode-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2 - Scheduler QuartzScheduler~application_$_application started.

2018-07-06 11:51:44,974 [INFO] from com.typesafe.akka.extension.quartz.QuartzSchedulerExtension in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2 - Setting up scheduled job 'HELLO_ACTOR', with 'com.typesafe.akka.extension.quartz.QuartzCronSchedule@6a6c7b3b'

2018-07-06 11:51:45,005 [INFO] from com.typesafe.akka.extension.quartz.QuartzSchedulerExtension in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2 - Setting up scheduled job 'CLEANUP_ACTOR', with 'com.typesafe.akka.extension.quartz.QuartzCronSchedule@2c32247d'
```

Acotrs should be triggered every 10 seconds. Any reason why this do not work, or what should I add and where?

Here is [code on the github](https://github.com/sleski/play-akka-quartz-example).

Answer (score 1):

You still need to schedule in the code to declare which message needs to be sent and to which actor. In `Scala` you would do:

```
QuartzSchedulerExtension(context.system).schedule("HELLO_ACTOR", someActor, "Hello from the Quartz scheduler")
QuartzSchedulerExtension(context.system).schedule("CLEANUP_ACTOR", someOtherActor, "Clean up from the Quartz scheduler")
```

If you want to stop one of these you can use the method `cancelJob`:

```
QuartzSchedulerExtension(context.system).cancelJob("HELLO_ACTOR")
```

Comment: If you check my github project, I schedule actors in this class:
https://github.com/sleski/play-akka-quartz-example/blob/master/app/modules/QuartzSchedulerHelper.java#L37

Answer (score 1):

Your log snippet does not indicate that your actors are registered with the scheduler. What it does show is that the Quartz jobs are successfully scheduled: in your configuration, `akka.quartz.schedules.HELLO_ACTOR` and `akka.quartz.schedules.CLEANUP_ACTOR` are *jobs*, not actors, despite what you've named them. (I recommend renaming those jobs to avoid confusion.)

Considering your [`QuartzSchedulerHelper`](https://github.com/sleski/play-akka-quartz-example/blob/master/app/modules/QuartzSchedulerHelper.java#L28), it doesn't appear that your actors are registered with the scheduler:

```
List<String> actors = Arrays.asList(HelloActor.NAME, CleanupRunner.NAME);
for (String name : actors) {
  ActorRef actor = registry.actorFor(name);
  schedule(quartzSchedulerExtension, actor, name, RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(10));
}
```

`actorFor` takes an [actor path](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/general/addressing.html#what-is-an-actor-path-) as an argument. What you're passing to that method is the actor's name. Use the actor path:

```
String actorPath = "/user/" + name
ActorRef actor = registry.actorFor(actorPath)
```

You might also want to try the following actor path:

```
String actorPath = "akka://application/user/" + name
```

Comment: I added logger before schedule() method:
`LOG.info("Actor Path = " + actor.path());`
and logs looks like below:
`Actor Path = akka://application/CLEANUP_ACTOR`
`Actor Path = akka://application/HELLO_ACTOR`
 is it correct?