# How to create a trigger in akka quartz, which will start executing a job only once in special time

Tags: java, scala, quartz-scheduler

for example i want to execute my code in 2019/01/09 in 22:00, how can i do it?
here is my code, but it doesn't working:

```
val trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger 
                            .withIdentity("Trigger", "Group")
                            .startAt( new Date(2019,1,9, 16,45))
                            .build()
```

Comment: Can you post the code of schedule configured for the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Below code should work to execute your code at 2019/01/09 in 22:00:

```
val cronExpression = "0 0 22 9 JAN ? 2019"   //At 22:00:00pm, on the 9th day, in January, in 2019
val trigger: CronTrigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
    .withIdentity(triggerName, jobGroup)
    .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(cronExpression))
    .forJob(jobName, jobGroup)
    .build
```

Comment: thanks, i have tried to schedule it using actor, but nothing happened, can you help? : val ex = context.actorOf(Executor.props(client))
      QuartzSchedulerExtension(system).createSchedule("O",None,"0 8 15 10 JAN ? 2019")
      QuartzSchedulerExtension(system).schedule("O", ex, ExecuteNow)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51207846/akka-quartz-scheduler-does-not-trigger-the-jobs should be helpful.